# Autoload no encuentra una classe

Tags: php, composer, phpunit

Estoy probando de testear una aplicación desarrollada con PHP, cuando quiero usar PHPUnit me sale el error:

```
Warning: require_once(/vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/app/tests/PersonTest.php on line 5
```

tests/PersonTest.php:

```
<?php
  namespace Tests;
  require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/vendor/autoload.php';
  use Model\Person;
  use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
  class PersonTest extends TestCase{}
```

composer.json:

```
{"autoload": {
"psr-4": {
  "Config\\": "config/",
  "Model\\": "model/",
  "Repository\\": "repository/",
  "Services\\": "services/",
  "Templates\\": "templates/",
  "View\\": "view/",
  "Api\\": "api/",
  "Controller\\": "controller/"
 }},
"autoload-dev": {
 "psr-4": {
  "Tests\\": "tests/"
}},
  "require-dev": {
 "phpunit/phpunit": "^10.5",
}}
```

model/person.php:

```
<?php
namespace Model;
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/vendor/autoload.php';
class Person{}
```

El require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/vendor/autoload.php'; Me funciona en todo el proyecto.

EDIT:
Si en las dos clases pongo:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

en vez de

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

el test funciona bien.

Comment: ya ejecutaste el `composer autoload dump`?

Comment: puede ser que los namespace en los archivos no concuerden con lo declarado